# Ubuntu hardy to intrepid upgrade hung on starting bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.04, ubuntu-8.10

I have no bluetooth. Preliminary googling indicates that is probably an issue with some usb devices.  I had an external drive, a mouse and a network dongle attached.

It is just stalled during the Installing the Upgrades phase - the last commands were "Creating device nodes"

Cancel will leave the system in a broken state.

What next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bets are on the network dongle - remove it, install, then plug it back in.

Comment: But I have to kill the install that is currently in progress.  Will it matter that it is in a broken state?

Comment: no it won't - you are installing anyway. :) curious to know - what make and model of network dongle?

Comment: It's a netgear dongle. Can't remember the make.  It's always been a problem.

Comment: Wireless? Trawl the Ubuntu forums to make sure the dongle is supported, or there are workarounds.

Comment: netgear WG111T wireless usb

Comment: Oh it's supported just poorly and it's what I have so it's what I use.  I've been using it with Hardy for quite some time with WICD but it is unreliable and sometimes interferes with booting.

Comment: read this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=258732 seems like it should only be plugged in after boot. Get a new one, they are not expensive nowadays.

Comment: Any suggestions what to get?  I need something available in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

If the upgrade is past the stage of downloading packages you may be able to do an apt-get dist-upgrade -f to repair it if you interrupt it.